# Sorting matrix without flattening, numpy

Tags: python, numpy

This was an exercise in scipy lectures(3.2.5)

Q: Combine ravel , sort and reshape .

A: `np.reshape(np.sort(np.ravel(a)), a.shape)`

Q: Look at the axis keyword for sort and rewrite the previous exercise.

A: ?

Comment: Thank you @NilsWerner, soled :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [`np.sort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) you can use `axis=None` to flat the array. Try:

```
import numpy as np

np.sort(a, axis=None).reshape(a.shape)
```

Comment: Excuse me @francesco-nazzaro :-( If I had read the documentation well then the question wasn't necessary :-(